# Check if JSON file exist, then require it

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to check if a JSON file exists, then require it, if not, create it. That's already done, but when using the jsonfile in the code, I get `ReferenceError: config is not defined

Code:

```
const cleverbot = require("cleverbot.io"),
    clever = new cleverbot(config.cleverbotUser, config.cleverBotToken);

fs.readFile("config.json", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Config file doesnot exist, creationg one.");

        //Default config values
        let obj = {
            cleverbotUser: "TOKEN",
            cleverBotToken: "TOKEN"
        };

        jsonfile.spaces = 4;
        jsonfile.writeFile("config.json", obj, (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    } else {
        global.config = require("./config.json");
    }
});
```

How would I check whether the JSON file exists before using it, without causing errors?

Comment: where do you define the var `config` you use in line 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config not defined is about the config object using in second line

```
 clever = new cleverbot(config.cleverbotUser, config.cleverBotToken);
```

it is surely not defined, you may have forgotten to require it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should define your config variable first. It can be empty or populated with some default data.

```
const config = {
   cleverbotUser: "", 
   cleverBotToken: ""
}
```

Then try to load values from file and the very end initialize your `cleverbot` object. The only condition for this method is that your class can run with those arguments, if not you should use `try catch` block and throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

You can use try catch for this.

```
try
{
const cleverbot = require("cleverbot.io"), 
clever = new cleverbot(config.cleverbotUser, config.cleverBotToken);
require('fs').exists("config.json", function(exists) {
if (exists) {
     fs.readFile("config.json", (err, data) => {
     if (err) {
        console.log("Config file doesnot exist, creationg one.");

    //Default config values
    let obj = {
        cleverbotUser: "TOKEN",
        cleverBotToken: "TOKEN"
    };

    jsonfile.spaces = 4;
    jsonfile.writeFile("config.json", obj, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
} else {
    global.config = require("./config.json");
}
});
}
});
 }
catch (e) {
if (e instanceof Error && e.code === "MODULE_NOT_FOUND")
    console.log("Can't load foo!");
else
    throw e;
}
```

The try catch will handle errors in loading modules and the file exists will handle the json file to see if it is found.

Comment: This just masks the problem, rather than solving it.